# What is the probability of selecting a white ball given a bag with $3$ red and $5$ white balls and a bag with $4$ and $8$ white balls?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

One bag-A contains $3$ red and $5$ white balls.
Second bag-B contains $4$ red and $8$ white balls.

If a blind man is presented with these two bags and allowed to pick a single ball from any of the above(only 1 ball, not 1 ball from each) then what is the probability of picking white ball by him?

I tried it and came to an answer $31/48$, but I am not sure if I am right.

Following is my answer, please correct me if I am wrong:-

- For bag-A, probability is $\dfrac{5}{8}$ for white
- For bag-B, probability is $\dfrac{2}{3}$ for white

But chance of getting either bag is $50\%$, so adding them

**Total probability = $\left(\dfrac{5}{8}\times \dfrac{1}{2}\right) +\left(\dfrac{2}{3} \times \dfrac{1}{2}\right) = \dfrac{31}{48}$**

My question is..

**Am i right? And if yes, is my method right?**

P.S.- This is my first question on this site so pardon me if I am making any mistakes, sorry.

Comment: Yes, you are right. You are using the Law of Total Probability (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)).

Comment: You do have a typo when you wrote $(2/3\color{red}{+}1/2)$.  Be careful when using *'s here as they might initiate bold or italics.  For proper math symbols and equations, visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to type with $\LaTeX$ and MathJax.

Comment: Maybe the blind man always draws balls from the heavier of the two bags. Why can't they just say they are drawing a ball at random from a bag chosen at random, using uniform distributions for each choice, if that's what they mean?

Comment: Thank you very much @kludg and Jmoravitz. And to user144527 blind man takes randomly in this given scenario.